# Why does the output contain a blank line at the end?

Tags: linux, awk

My file is just one line:

```
$ cat employee-one-line.txt
101,John Doe:102,Jason Smith:103,Raj Reddy:104,Anand Ram:105,Jane Miller
$
```

But executing the following `awk` script, it prints a redundant empty line at end:

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{ RS=":" } {print $2}' employee-one-line.txt
John Doe
Jason Smith
Raj Reddy
Anand Ram
Jane Miller

$
```

Why is there a blank line at end?

Comment: To debug output formatting issues, it's a good idea to place characters around the output so you can see what's coming from where. In this case change `{print $2}` to `{print "<" $2 ">"}` and it should be much clearer what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have set the record separator to a colon, the last record is `105,Jane Miller`, followed by a newline character. `print` adds an `ORS` (output record separator) to the end of things that it prints, so you end up with two.

The default behaviour would be that awk consumes the newline as the record separator, then adds it back in whenever you `print`.

In order to make awk swallow the newline in this case, one option would be to add it to your field separator:

```
awk -F'[,\n]' 'BEGIN{ RS=":" } {print $2}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you defined `RS=':'`, a newline is no longer a record separator, so the newline terminating your file got appended to "Jane Miller".